# Ruby Array#select with an options hash to match on

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array of hashes that I would like to search on, and I would like to write a method that takes an options hash as an argument and return all elements in the array that match against all key/value pairs dynamically, and I'm having trouble figuring it out.

```
my_array = [
  {
    foo: 'a',
    bar: 'b',
    baz: 'c'
  },
  {
    foo: 1,
    bar: 2,
    baz: 3
  },
  {
    foo: 'A',
    bar: 'B',
    baz: 'C'
  },
  {
    foo: 11,
    bar: 12,
    baz: 13
  }
]

# takes an opts hash and returns all elements for which all
# all key/value pairs match
def search_by(opts)
  opts.each do |k, v|
    self.select { |f| f[k] == f[v] }
  end
end

my_array.search_by(foo: 'a', bar: 'b')
# should return { foo: 'a', bar: 'b', baz: 'c' }
```

I've tried a couple different ways to dynamically compose a block to pass to #select based on similar questions on SO, but I haven't had much luck and haven't been able to find this exact use case.  What's the best way to dynamically #select with multiple conditions while only having to execute #select once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be trying to over complicate this. How about this

```
my_array = [
  {foo: 'a', bar: 'b', baz: 'c'},
  {foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 3},
  {foo: 'A', bar: 'B', baz: 'C'},
  {foo: 11, bar: 12, baz: 13}
]
finder = {foo: 'a', bar: 'b'} 
my_array.select {|h| h.values_at(*finder.keys) == finder.values }
#=> [{:foo=>"a", :bar=>"b", :baz=>"c"}]
```

`Hash#values_at` uses the given keys to return the appropriate values which in your case should match the values for those keys in the "finder" `Hash`.

To make it work explicitly the way you explained we can define a singleton method for `my_array` as such:

```
my_array.define_singleton_method(:search_by) do |opts|
  self.select {|h| h.values_at(*opts.keys) == opts.values}
end

my_array.search_by(foo: 'a', bar: 'b') 
#=> [{:foo=>"a", :bar=>"b", :baz=>"c"}]
my_array.search_by(foobar: 'n')
#=> []
my_array << {foo: 11,bar: 15,baz: 'c'}
my_array.search_by(foo: 11)
#=>[{:foo=>11, :bar=>12, :baz=>13}, {:foo=>11, :bar=>15, :baz=>"c"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Hash#>=`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Hash.html#method-i-3E-3D):

> Returns `true` if *other* is subset of *hash* or equals to *hash*.

```
my_array.select { |h| h >= finder }
#=> [{:foo=>"a", :bar=>"b", :baz=>"c"}]
```

Comment: You made my day! I was about to suggest `my_array.select { |h| h.merge(finder) == h }`, but what you have is perfect.